# How to Cache SOAP Requests and Response in java

Tags: java, caching, apache-axis

is there a mechanism to Cache the SOAP Request and response so that the performance can be improved....

we can reduce unnecessary same requests hitting the server for fetching the same response.

by the way im using AXIS2 for Webservice with AXIOM.

Awaiting your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no mechanism of doing so in `AXIS`, but then you can always buld your own custom cache using a simple map or using [guava-google libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply...will try to mplement the same. its just the library inclusion right?..is there a need of server for this cache again?

Comment: If you can help me in integration methodologies for Axis2 and guava-google libraries

Comment: You have to do a bit of coding, On request you need to identify whats unique in that request, use that as key and response as value, store this in your cache(map), On next request, extract key from the request , look for that key in you map, if you get it there its a cache hit(you have the response) as value, else hit the target and get the value from there. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: thanks for the timely help....I dint know what to do if Axis2 doesnt provide SOAP request Caching. thought off doing it manually all the way. Thanks, your answer reduced my time. Accepting and up-voting it.

Comment: Do you have any idea on WS02 Carbon ... used for Caching as well. It seems a bit complicated.. and it comes with inbuilt tomcat.

Comment: I am glad that i could be of any help to you. About WSO2 Carbon, sorry i never worked on that so no idea.